# Can't populate observableArray with data from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I can't insert any values inside my observableArray when I'm getting data from server, but other elements get data.

JS **markup**:

```
var itemViewModel = {
    item: {},
    isLoaded: ko.observable(false),
    comments: ko.observableArray([]),
    loadcontent: function (getID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/item/details/' + getID,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                itemViewModel.item = data;
                $.each(data.Comments, function (index) {
                    itemViewModel.comments.push(data.Comments[index]);
                    console.log(data.Comments[index]);
                    console.log(itemViewModel.comments);
                });
                itemViewModel.isLoaded(true);
                itemDetailBindings();
                console.log(itemViewModel.item);
                console.log(itemViewModel.comments);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**RESULT**:

```
Object
[]
Object
[]
Object
[]
[]
Object
[]
```

Comment: Is the server returning JSON? Try console.logging just `data` in the success function of the Ajax call.

Comment: Yes, the data gives item value but leaves comment without value

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, but it may solve the problem... why not declare your each statement as `$.each(data.Comments, function (index, theComment) {`?  This would allow the array population to be written as follows: `itemViewModel.comments.push(theComment);` I believe `itemViewModel.comments.push(this);` would work, as well, with or without the extra parameter passed to the anonymous function

Comment: Problem that I needed to add new line `itemViewModel.comments([])` before `$.each` why is that, why isn't the variable already defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need `itemViewModel` inside `success` method,

```
success: function (data) {
                    item = data;
                    $.each(data.Comments, function (index) {
                        comments.push(data.Comments[index]);
                        console.log(data.Comments[index]);
                        console.log(comments);
                    });
                    isLoaded(true);
                    itemDetailBindings();
                    console.log(item);
                    console.log(comments);
                }
```